# How can I disable that windows get maximized if i put them on top of the display?

Tags: window-management

I never want to maximize a window when dragging the window to the top of the screen, but it happens most of the time and is really annoying!

I just want to drag the window to the top of the screen. Is there any way to change this default behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can customize this with gsettings in Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior edge-tiling false
```

Use `true` to revert to default behavior.

Or use the graphical dconf Editor. You need to install it if you haven't done it already:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Once it is installed, open it and search for the entry:

```
org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behaviour edge-tiling
```

There you'll see the default setting:

```
true
```

you can switch this to:

```
false
```

to have the desired behavior.

Comment: it works directly without log off. thanks!

Comment: I was just about to ask this. Will it disable side-tiling too?

Comment: I am like a year late, but! This command will disable dragging to tile windows in any direction, including to the sides. You can still use keyboard shortcuts to tile, though.